# Select data based on datestamp with sqlite3 query

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 to access data in a database based on a value for the datestamp. Please consider the following code:

```
live_db_conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/user/Documents/database.db')
time_period = (dt.now() - timedelta(seconds=time)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
time_period_data = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Datestamp > {}'.format(str(time_period)), live_db_conn)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Datestamp > 12:33:33': near ":33": syntax error
```

I don't understand where this error comes from, because if I run the following code:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Datestamp FROM table1 LIMIT 10', live_db_conn)
print(df)
```

I get the following output:

```
Datestamp
0  10:46:54
1  10:46:59
2  10:47:04
3  10:47:09
4  10:47:14
5  10:47:19
6  10:47:24
7  10:47:29
8  10:47:34
9  10:47:39
```

So it seems (to me at least) that my sql query is correct. I've tried to do `.format(time_period)` instead of `.format(str(time_period))` but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Question:** How do I select the portion of the data that corresponds to the selected time period?

**Edit:** It seems that something is going wrong with the minutes in the timestamp. When I ran the code again I got the same error but with a different timestamp:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Datestamp > 12:49:10': near ":49": syntax error
```

So I'd say that the syntax error has something to do with the minutes in the timestamp..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
time_period_data = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Datestamp > {}'.format(str(time_period)), live_db_conn)
```

I did:

```
time_period_data = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Datestamp > "{}"'.format(time_period), live_db_conn)
```

which solved the problem!